# How do I group the Author names here?

Tags: database, db2

In the table shown in the picture, I would like to concatenate the names of authors who worked on the same article.
For example, first line would be "Ahmed Anwar Nasr and Islam M Abdelaziz" and second line would be "Ahmed Anwar Nasr and Omar Sayed Said"
How can this be done?
I have thought about using the group by clause, but this only works on group functions
[image: Table]

Comment: I am using DB2, but I am asking as a general concept. How do I group two entries from two different records, but the same column based on a common value in another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `listagg` like in the following example

```
SELECT listagg(writers, ' and '), title
  FROM <tablename>
 GROUP BY title
```